# Charge created by Stripe inherits Metadata from Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, pseudocode

I'd like that all charges created by Stripe from subscriptions inherits from the metadata holded by the subscription.

Is there a way to do it ? I can't find any explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Contacted the technical support, it's not possible for now.